# How to save a tensor to a file in TensorFlow using the low level (C) interface?

Tags: c, tensorflow

Using the low level Operations in TensorFlow, I try to save a Tensor (its actual value) to a disk, but cannot find how to.
If the data is e.g. a UInt8 matrix representing an image then I can easily do EncodeJpeg to create the Content and then use WriteFile to write the generated Content to a file with a given name. Similarly EncodeWav works the same way.
On the other hand, if I just want to save a matrix with numbers, there is no "EncodeData", "TensorToContent" or similar Operation to convert the Tensor into a Content, what can be saved with WriteFile.
I can get the Tensor as an output from my Graph and then save it outside the Graph, but my purpose is to do it inside.

Comment: If the data is `uint8_t`, why did you just not write it with `fwrite` or `write` ?

Comment: The data is not necessarily UInt8. It was just an example of a case, when data (in a tensor) can be converted to a Content, that is accepted by WriteFile. The other issue is that I want to do it inside the Graph, not outside it. As said in the OP, I can get the Tensor as an output of the Graph (RunSession) and then save it with old style file operations, but that is not the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time, but finally found a solution, though it might not be the best. If you can improve, you're welcome.

So, I use the Save/Restore raw operation pair. It is relatively straight forward, once found.

"Save" has two tensor Inputs, one tensor InputList and one Attribute. The first tensor (scalar string) has to give the filename. The second tensor (1D string) contains the names you want to give to the tensors in the file (for Restore purposes later). The InputList is actually a collection of the tensors to be saved. The Attribute is a list of data types of the tensors to be saved.

"Restore" is also simple. It has two tensor Inputs, one tensor Output, one type Attribute and one optional integer Attribute. The first Input (scalar string) gives the file name or file pattern if more files can be looked at. The second Input (scalar string) gives the name (see above in "Save") of the tensor you want to find in the files. The Output is the loaded tensor itself. The type Attribute specifies what type is the tensor that will be loaded. The optional Attribute can be used if tensors with the same name exist in multiple files matching the pattern, telling which one is preferred.

The only thing to be careful with is the InputList in "Save". When the "Save" raw operation is added to the Graph at design time, the number of inputs in the Inputlist has to be given, as well as the (same number!) of types in the type list argument. This means that at runtime, when giving the actual names of the tensors and giving the tensorlist as the InputList, you cannot change anymore the number and data type of the tensors.